# With wiremock how can I match against the wiremock server URL in the body of a POST?

Tags: java, jsonpath, wiremock, osisoft

I'm using Wiremock with a client calling the OSISoft PI Web API and I'm having issues matching against the POST body to the request defined [here](https://docs.osisoft.com/bundle/pi-web-api-reference/page/help/controllers/batch/actions/execute.html) as with Wiremock the POST body will have a URL containing the randomly generated port. e.g.

```
{
  "1": {
    "Method": "POST",
    "Resource": "http://localhost:24353/piwebapi/assetdatabases/D0NxzXSxtlKkGzAaZhKOB-KABJ2buwfWrkye3YhdL2FOUAUEhMQUZTMDRcQgYUUEVSRk9STUFOQ0UgVEVTVElORw/elements",
    "Content": "{\"Name\":\"New Element\"}"
  }
}
```

How can I match against the URL in the Resource element where the port number will change between test runs? Obviously I cannot use templating for requests like I would with responses.

From reviewing the docs on [request matching](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/) I see that using `equalToJson` with placeholders or `matchesJsonPath` with a regex expression may be an option but I'm not clear on the exact syntax. Or is there a simpler option that I'm missing?

Comment: @Eugene responses have templating http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/ where you can use {{request.baseUrl}} to do the same thing as I've used that on other matchers to return a response with a link. But sadly there isn't the same support for requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [wiremock-user](https://groups.google.com/g/wiremock-user/c/ziIWcf0SQ4s/m/e5heJDbsAQAJ) Google Group

> If you don't need to match anything in particular for that element you could use a JSON placeholder e.g. `"Resource": "${json-unit.any-string}".`

> If you do need to match the part after the port number then you can use the regex form e.g.: `"Resource": "${json-unit.regex}.*/piwebapi/assetdatabases/D0NxzXSxtlKkGzAaZhKOB-KABJ2buwfWrkye3YhdL2FOUAUEhMQUZTMDRcQgYUUEVSRk9STUFOQ0UgVEVTVElORw/elements"}"`